Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed error in Blazor Server Application
I am building a Blazor app using Dapper.
I have a stored procedure with the following code, which executes perfectly when I test it in SSMS:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GlobalCnsldSalesCurrencyConversionSelectSingle]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Currency nvarchar(50),
    @CalendarDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FiscalPeriod int;

    SELECT @FiscalPeriod = CalendarFiscalPeriod 
    FROM GlobalCnsldSalesDateDim 
    WHERE CalendarDate = @CalendarDate
    
    SELECT Rate
    FROM GlobalCnsldSalesCurrencyConversion
    WHERE FromCurrency = @Currency 
      AND ToCurrency = 'USD' 
      AND FiscalPeriodSid = @FiscalPeriod
END

I call this from a method in my app like this:
public async Task<ExchangeRateDto> GetCnsldCurrencyExchangeRate(string currency, DateTime calendarDate) =>
    await _db.LoadDataAzureSingleSP<ExchangeRateDto, dynamic>(storedProcedure: "dbo.procGlobalCnsldSalesCurrencyConversionSelectSingle", new { Currency = currency, CalendarDate = calendarDate });

The LoadDataAzureSingleSP code is:
public async Task<T> LoadDataAzureSingleSP<T, U>(string storedProcedure, U parameters)
{
    string connectionString = _configAzure.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringAzure);

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        return await connection.QuerySingleAsync<T>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}

I have checked the parameters I pass to the method and they are correct, but I still get the following error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I am at a total loss as to what is causing this.
Any ideas?

I'm guessing CalendarFiscalPeriod is actually a datetime, and therefore causing the problem. It can't be something like your WHERE clauses, as that would implicitly convert the int to a datetime (due to datetime having a higher data type precedence), which is allowed. Therefore the only place i can see that would cause the error is where you assign the value of @FiscalPeriod. Can you provide us with an actual [mre] with sample DDL and DML?

Ensure that the CalendarDate being passed from your Blazor app is correctly typed as DateTime. Since you mentioned that the parameters are correct, this is less likely to be the issue, but it’s worth double-checking. Also, if CalendarDate in the GlobalCnsldSalesDateDim table is an int or something other than datetime, you should convert it explicitly in your WHERE clause:  WHERE CAST(CalendarDate AS datetime) = @CalendarDate

I've learned to not trust such claims over the years, unfortunately, @DaleK .

@SathyapriyaMuthukrishnan  that's not great advice. WHERE CAST(CalendarDate AS datetime) could easily make the query non-SARGable. If the data type of CalendarDate isn't a date and time value already, that's a bigger problem; the design needs fixing not the query.

yeah, i understand

What is the code of LoadDataAzureSingleSP, doesn't seem like a standard function

As an aside, why use a variable and assign to it, and not just JOIN to GlobalCnsldSalesDateDim in your query?

Please use the [edit] feature to improve your post, @user10070084 , not the comments.

And what does: select user_type_id from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('GlobalCnsldSalesDateDim') and name = 'CalendarFiscalPeriod' outputs

That statement outputs: 56

Strange. How is: ExchangeRateDto defined? And are you calling correct database? Perhaps there's another SP which uses some other input

ExchangeDateDto has a single variable (double), which is where I store the exchange rate to be applied.

The facts
The error of

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

tells us that:

the error happened at the RDBMS, so it successfully reached the RDBMS
it is an issue with converting datetime to int
the stored procedure is known, otherwise it would complain about that

Hence, you will need to figure out where the value conversion could happen.
Contemplating on the facts
The first such place is the declaration, notably the line of
@CalendarDate datetime

which expects to receive a datetime and, if you happen to pass an int, then you will get the error quoted above. If this was the culprit, then something converted your DateTime to an int. If that's the case, then this int probably represents in its integer way the time passed since a given moment in the past. CORRECTION as Thom A pointed out in the comment-section via this fiddle, this should not be a problem, at least, not generating the error message that you had. However, it is still something to check, as it may be a problem in past or future versions of the product.
The second possible line where this may happen is
SELECT @FiscalPeriod = CalendarFiscalPeriod FROM GlobalCnsldSalesDateDim WHERE CalendarDate = @CalendarDate

In which case CalendarFiscalPeriod is a datetime and its implicit conversion to int fails.
So you will need to determine which of the two candidates is causing the bug for you.
Epistemology: How do I determine the culprit?
There are several ways to do so. You could look into the logs of your RDBMS and see how the stored procedure has been called, what was actually passed and whether that matches your expectation. If it was called correctly, then the bug is inside the stored procedure and your manual tests were just not making it manifest. Think about a case when there is no fiscal period to be assigned, for example. However, if the call itself was wrong, then the bug is in your C# code and you will need to fix it there.
Another way to determine it is to temporarily eliminate the second possible culprit (assign some hard-coded int to @FiscalPeriod in a temporarily altered stored procedure or a temporary copy of it) and see whether the issue still happens. If so, then you have a C# error when passing the parameter. If not, then you have an error in the second culprit.
The solution
The solution greatly depends on what the problem is. Either you will need to adjust your C# code so that it will pass the parameters in a correct manner, or you just need to convert datetime to int in an explicit manner when you assign @FiscalPeriod. See https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/convert-datetime-to-integer
